# Database design implementing support for different languages

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, foreign-key-relationship

Today I was practicing database design, for example I was trying to build a database design where I would like to store my favorite shows. I have normlaised this database to the third form (at least I think I have). But I have faced a problem with this design, actually, how can I preform a such query:

- Is there any show that has language (let's say Italian) and status Emitting and there are more than 5 episodes available?

I think I have made a mistake with the language and show_internation_data table, but I am not sure...

Also if you could tell me how bad this design is and what to improve, or just throw an awesome article, that would be awesome!!

**Diagram:**

Here is the image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/abhwx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. There is a problem with the show_international_data but that's not the only issue with this design.

I would remove the show_ID column from show_languages and add it to show_international_data instead. This re-oredering of tables will allow you to write a query to answer your question.

```
select show_ID
  from show s left join show_international_date sid          
    on s.show_ID = sid.show_ID
 where s.episodes_available > 5
   and sid.status           = 'Emitting'
   and sid.language_id      = (select language_ID 
                                 from show_languages 
                                where language = 'Italian')
```

Beyond this specific question however you should perhaps consider the following:

- Do genre, theme and summary really vary depending on language?
- ...and do rating & cover_img NOT vary with language?
- show to show_producer should probably be a many to many relation.
- genre to show & theme to show could also potentially be many to many.

If I was developing this I would also create tables for status, genre & theme and store the IDs in show_international_data (or whatever table they end up in) rather than storing them as varchar